# Resizable Text component in scrollContent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to display app logs at scrollContent.
I have list of logs where log is :

```
public class Log
{
      public string LogType {get; set;}
      public LogType LogType {get; set}
}
```

To display log message should I use string or StringBuilder at one Text component with supporting richText or make Text prefab foreach list element?
How to use scrollContent and Text? Text Resizeing should depend on text lenght.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a ScrollView with a child Text object. The child text object should have a ContentSizeFitter component attached to it so it scales its size based on its contents. The scroll view should be set to *vertical scrolling* and the text's content size fitter's vertical constraint should be set to *preferred.*

I solved a similar need in this same way, and it works great.

See https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/scroll-view and https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html